# Logarithmic function that starts at origin and reaches for 1 as x goes to infinity

Tags: limits, logarithms

I'm trying to obtain a logarithmic function with characteristics such as when $\lim_{x \to\infty} f(x)$, the function diverges at 1.

Any ideas?

**Update**:
I was playing around and I think I accidentidly created such function, but I'm not sure if it actually fulfills my functional demands.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That shows the limit is one, not that the function is diverging to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Diverges at $1$" as $x$ grows makes no sense. As $x \to \infty$ the logarithm grows without bound.

If you want a convex function with a horizontal asymptote of $1$ consider
$$
1 - e^{-ax}.
$$

You can adjust the value of the positive constant $a$ to change the rate at which you creep up to $1$.

**Edit** in response to comment.

You can use
$$
L - e^{-ax}.
$$
for any $L < 1$ you like.

Comment: That function looks very similar to the one I found. But is there a way for the function to never creep up to 1? That's what I meant with diverges.

Comment: See my comment. I hope the downvote isn't yours ...

Comment: If I use L < 1 the function does not start at origin. No downvotes in here from me

Comment: To start from the origin use $L(1-\exp(-ax))$. You should have been able to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help. Appreciate it.